# How to overwrite get_queryset method to only display the objects that are contained within a many-to-many field in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-filters

I have an API that has two models. `Buildings` and `BuildingGroup`. Every building is within a building group.

I want to overwrite the `get_queryset` method to display only buildings that are within a Building group.

My models:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, 
    buildings = models.ManyToManyField('Building')
```

My view so far:

```
class BuildingGroupAPIView(
                      mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      ListAPIView):

    permission_classes          = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    authentication_classes      = [SessionAuthentication]

    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer
    passed_id = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = BuildingGroup.buildings.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(project__icontains=query)
        return qs

    def get_object(self):
        request = self.request
        passed_id = request.GET.get('id', None) or self.passed_id
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        obj = None
        if passed_id is not None:
            obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, id=passed_id)
            self.check_object_permissions(request, obj)
        return obj
```

My serializer:

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Building

        fields = (
                'name',
                'height'
                'width'
        )
```

this shows me a list of all Buildings. Now I want to change that method, but I couldn't manage so far.

I tried:

```
qs = BuildingGroup.objects.buildings.all()
qs = BuildingGroup.buildings.all()
qs = BuildingGroup.buildings_set.all()
```

and I tried looping through the BuildingGroup...

Has anyone an idea? Help is of course very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: share your entire view code

Comment: Thanks Anjaneyulu, I updated it with my view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use reverse relationship to query it. Please checkout below code. I didn't test it but it should work.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Building.objects.all()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(buildinggroup_set__description__icontains=query)
    return qs
```

Comment: thank you or the help. Unfortunately it gives me an ```AttributeError: type object 'Building' has no attribute 'buildings' ``` The buildings attribute is part of the BuildingGroup model

Comment: @Micromegas oh! yeah, that's a typo mistake, updated the query now. Please check it.

Comment: thank you very much! It works now! I just figured that I have a mistake in my models, since all my Buildings instances are in my m2m field by default (and not only the ones I want to choose). But your code works flawless, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need need to filter out with m2m relation,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Building.objects.all()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(name=query)
    return qs
```

Comment: thank you for the help. When I do this, every value of the buildings I want to display turns to null. Maybe I have an error in my logic....?

Comment: *"I want to display turns to null."* I don't get that. Can you clarify that for me?

Comment: @JPG @Micromegas is using `BuildingSerializer` so , I guess we should not return `BuildingGroup` queryset.

Comment: yes of course: I want to display the buildings which are in the m2m relation. The buildings have attribute like a name, height and width. These attributes are displayed as ```null```.

Comment: I added my serializer

Comment: @Micromegas Can you add a screenshot/response of your current output?

Comment: @Micromegas I've updated my answer anyway. Check it out.

Comment: thank you very much! It works now perfectly! I just figured that I have a mistake in my models, since all my Buildings instances are in my m2m field by default (and not only the ones I want to choose). But your code works great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First make a slight change to your **buildings** field in **BuildingGroup** model like so, removing the quote so it calls the **Building** model

```
buildings = models.ManyToManyField(Building)
```

So, Say you have two **Building** models as follows,

```
building1 = Building.objects.get(id=1)
building2 = Building.objects.get(id=2)
```

and a **BuildingGroup** model like so,

```
building_group = BuildingGroup.objects.get(id=2)
```

You then add the following **buildings** to the **BuildingGroup** like so,

```
building_group.buildings.add(building1)
building_group.buildings.add(building2)
```

To get the list of all buildings added to the **BuildingGroup** instance, you use

```
building_group.buildings.all()
```

Let me know how it goes. Goodluck.

**EDIT**. You seem to be calling the whole model here:

```
qs = BuildingGroup.buildings.all()
```

it should be the BuildingGroup instance instead.

```
building_group = BuildingGroup.objects.get(id='id')
qs = building_group.buildings.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much OBAA. I don't quite understand. Where would you put the ```building1 = Building.objects.get(id=1)``` and the ```building_group.buildings.add(building1)```
? In my view I assume?

Comment: Yes in your view or model methods but you have to customize to your needs. They are just typical ways to fetch objects either a building object and adding it to a building_group object. i.e Updating the m2m.

Comment: ah ok I understand! Thank you very much!!